# My build is ok but d APK It fails.over 64k, I tried google's site to fix the 2 errors although I just get more errors

Tags: android, apk

Hello I get the 2 errors when trying to generate a signed APK. Although when I build the project it has O errors.

I have gone to the links tried to make the modifications but it comes up with more errors

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Configure your app for multidex
Setting up your app project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make the following modifications to your app project, depending on the minimum Android version your app supports.

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
However, if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you must use the multidex support library as follows:

Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

This is the point I though I should put it in my code. I looked around and tried a couple more locations although I keep getting errors.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adventure.game"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName '1'
        versionNameSuffix '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

If anyone can help, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the 64k error in one of my apps, and the solution was not to use the multidex. 
My problem was that I was importing all the google services with this line in my dependencies: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`. Google brought 64k classes to my app, so I removed this compile line and imported only the services I needed (the location service). 
You can find the complete list [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).
And this worked for me.

I hope this will help you.